# Shift & Caps Lock not working (Win 10) - keep needing to reinstall keyboard driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard

The shift and caps lock keys have begun to stop working on my HP Stream 13 laptop. Uninstalling and reinstalling the keyboard driver temporarily fixes the issue, but it soon returns (i.e. within the same day). I've tried updating the driver but am told that my machine already has the latest driver version installed. The OS is Windows 10 Pro. Any ideas for possible causes/fixes?

Comment: Boot to the hardware diagnostics (should be accessible from BIOS/EFI firmware or via a key combination at boot - look up the user manual for your laptop) and run the test for the Keyboard, as that sounds like failing hardware (the driver isn't the issue and it's likely by uninstalling/re-installing the driver, you're clearing the error code that's disabling those keys,,, this should also be recorded in Event Viewer, but I'm not sure where)

Comment: Try to clean the keyboard under these keys.

Comment: I booted to the BIOS and found that a couple of the other keys also don't work (the F1 and cursor up keys). That suggests a hardware problem with the keyboard, but what I don't understand is why re-installing the windows keyboard driver seems to temporarily fix the problem\? For example, if the Shift key is broken, how can reinstalling the driver temporarily "fix" it?

Answer (score 1):

Try going on the keyboard settings from the settings pane and look for Caps lock settings. You can change its settings or revert it to default. Check if that works

Comment: I can't find caps lock settings anywhere???